# Image not found altough right relative path is specified

Tags: html

My website on my server does not want to show the on server saved image.
The path is relative and to my information correct, but I always get a 404 error.
Found no solution after browsing endlessly.

All nessecary information is found in the second picture posted.

[image: In the Browser]

[image: In PHPStorm]

Comment: Are you able to open the image via url directly in the browser? For example: `localhost:3000/{path}/image.jpeg`. That should tell you if you are having issues on the server or client side

Comment: No did not work either. Not the most advanced web dev ever so sorry if dumb but I tried this :http://my_cv_site/application/_images/title_image_me.jpeg", that did not work

Comment: What stack are you using? Are you 100% sure you have the correct path? Does `_images` get placed into a specific folder when you run the application?

Comment: On the second image you see the server path, and the path on the server is ident with mine locally.  What do you mean with what stack? I am pretty sure this is the right path, but as I said, now so knowledgable so I might got it wrong

Comment: Just by curiosity, what Framework are you using?

Comment: I am using a smaller more ligheweight one. Called Huge. Worked with it at school, and liked the model/view/controller system so I stuck with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, you use a Framework. The file you have in the `view` folder isn't the one you send to the browser, it's just a source file that will be used by your Framework entry point: `public/index.php`. Your root folder is therefore `public`.

Two things must then be understood:

1. Even though the line your type is in `application/view/index/index.php`, the browser will only see it as `index.php`, located at the base of your site (`http://localhost/index.php` or somethig like that). The relative path must therefore be written as relative to `public`.
2. As your root folder, `public`, is seen as `http://localhost` by the browser, you can't use `..`, there is nothing above the root of your website, for the browser. You must do one of the followings:

   1. Place your image in `public/_images` instead of `application/_images` (normally, all the files that can be sent without passing by the PHP preprocessor can go in `public`)
   2. Place it wherever you want and create a controller that maps a custom URL to your image. Something like `/images/(:any)` maps to a controller looking into your specific image folder (please, don't, it's not because you can that you should).

My advice: create a `public/img` folder and place it your images, then you load it with `<img src="/img/title_image_me.jpeg" alt="My picture">`. (The initial `/` is very important there!, it's understood as the root folder of your website, Linux-style).

Comment: This worked like a charm thanks! Thanks you for the insights!

Comment: A pleasure, I stumbled upon the very same problem when I started with Frameworks. I know how ou feel.